# Clojure apply string replace to each element in array

Tags: arrays, clojure

Given an array contains elements such as:

```
[":test" ":do_this" "dont" ":_another_one"]
```

I need to remove the `:` and replace it with a `empty string` which can be done using:

```
(clojure.string/replace element #":" "")
```

However how can I apply this to every element? I have looked at using the `apply` function but it doesn't seem to modify the elements, is this because they are in fact `immutable`?

```
(apply function collection)
```

Is what I've been looking at doing but no luck so far.

Comment: To clarify the functionality of the `apply` and `map` functions (as a supplement to the correct answer by Lee), `apply` will start as a call like this: `(apply f [1 2 3])` and do this: `(f 1 2 3)`, evaluating the function once by giving it all the elements of the list as arguments, resulting in a single output value; `map`, OTOH, will start as this: `(map f [1 2 3])` and do this `((f 1) (f 2) (f 3))`, where the function will be applied to each element of the original list, resulting in a new list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
(let [input [":test" ":do_this" "dont" ":_another_one"]
      updated (map #(clojure.string/replace % #":" "") input)]
  ...)
```

this returns a sequence instead of a vector, so use `mapv` if you want to create a new vector.